# Show that $f(x,y) = (e^x\cos y, e^x \sin y)$ is one to one on $E := \{(x,y):x \in \mathbb{R} ,0 < y < \frac{\pi}{2} \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse

Show that $f(x,y) = (e^x\cos y, e^x \sin y)$ is one to one on $E := \{(x,y):x \in \mathbb{R} ,0 < y < \frac{\pi}{2} \}$.

It is relatively obvious, but I don't know how to write it down, like "there's no restriction in this interval?".

This question had been ask many times; however, all of them show *why* the function is *not* 1-1, but not why it *is* 1-1 on this specific interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y), (x',y') \in E$ and $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$. Take norm on both sides to get $e^{2x}=e^{2x'}$ which gives $x=x'$. Now we have $\cos y =\cos y'$  and $\sin y=\sin y'$. This implies that $y-y'$ is a multiple of $2\pi$. But since $y,y' \ (0,\pi /2)$ the only possibility is $y=y'$.

Comment: how does the previous part implies −′  is a multiple of 2 ? and isn't (0,/2) the only possibility where  != y' ?

Comment: @GarlicSTAT That is what I am saying . I am making a more general statement that if we don't put any restriction on $y$ and $y'$ then the conclusion is $y-y'=2n\pi$ for some integer $n$. With the given restriction on the domain we must have $y=y'$.

Comment: oh! right! thanks